# Can a bubble be modelled convincingly using a ricci flow?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, ricci-flow

My knowledge of this type of geometry leaves a lot to be desired, but I have heard about the Ricci flow.

My understanding of the Ricci flow is that it models a "velocity" for each part of a shape as it transforms tending to a spherical shape and shrinks, or just tends to a spherical shape if given the condition that the shape must have a constant volume.

If my understanding is correct I would like to know if a bubble could be modeled by, rather than finding the velocity of the parts of the bubble based on its curvature, finding a force dependent on an appropriate factor. this force would apply to a given density of mass for the bubble to accelerate it, the condition that it must keep a constant volume would be applied. The initial state would be a random shape of any description.

Could this technique work? If not, then why not (other than the fact that it doesn't take air currents into account for the deformation of the bubble).